# How to push the selected checkboxses into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to collect the data from checkboxes and fill a property of a  model with them.

If I try this

```
$('input.box:checked').each(function (index, item) {
  selected.push($(item).next('label').text());
});
```

in selected I have only names.

If I try this

```
$('input.box:checked').each(function (index, item) {
   selected.push($(item).val());
});
```

in selected I have only id's

I need selected to be :

```
selected = [{id:1 , name: Minnie},{id:2 , name: Mickey}]...
```

Comment: You're only pushing a single value into the array. Have you tried pushing an object with the properties you want like so `selected.push({id: $(item).val(), name:$(item).next('label').text()});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an object with the desired properties to the array like so:

```
$('input.box:checked').each(function (index, item) {
  selected.push({
    id: $(item).val(), 
    name: $(item).next('label').text()
  });
});
```

Comment: so obvious , thanks daddygames, big help. sorry for stupid question